# Parse for string in string php

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

I have a problem with regular expressions in PHP.

I have a string: "NAPLAK ROSSO+S.ARG.+LACC.ARG.+NK", all of this words contain options like ROSSO,S.ARG, Are colors ROSSO = Red, s.arg = silver and so on.

Out of this string i need to generate a description like:

Material: Naplak,
Color: Red, Silver....
....

I thought, that there is going to be an array with laguage codes something like this:

```
$options = array(
    "ROSSO" => "COLOR_RED",
    "S.ARG" => "COLOR_SILVER"
);
```

Could you please help me to write a regular expression for this purpose?

Best regargs,
RussianRoot.

Comment: you don't want a regular expression here, as there are no "patterns", you are replacing actual words, if there's a mistake on the color's name (like a missing letter) even regex will fail. Just use a str_replace() with multiple needles. And you can just use explode to separate them as @Paul Moldovan suggested and "translate" the colours using the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need regex for this.  Probably easier and faster to do something like:

```
$item = explode(' ', "NAPLAK ROSSO+S.ARG.+LACC.ARG.+NK");
$args = explode('+', $item[1]);
$item = $item[0];

echo $item;
```

Gives us "NAPLAK"

```
print_r($args);
```

Gives us:

```
array(4) [ 'ROSSO', 'S.ARG', 'LACC.ARG.', 'NK' ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If they all are delimited by + then why don't you use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

That will give you an array with each element and then you can do whatever you want with it.

A different way is to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.str-replace.php) and replace "ROSSO" with "COLOR_RED" and so on.